# Scheduling cronjobs at specified time

Tags: macos, cron

I have scheduled some jobs in **crontab** which are to be run one by one, at some specific time. My script for crontab is :

```
15 10 * * * /Users/sri/files/BatchFF.sh
45 11 * * * /Users/sri/files/BatchGC.sh
15 13 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_GUI_FF.sh
45 14 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_GUI_GC.sh
15 16 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_Sim_FF.sh
45 17 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_Sim_GC.sh
```

These scripts ideally should start at 10:15, 11:45, 13:15, 14:45, and so on.
But the scripts are not starting as expected, rather they start at 10:15, 10:15, 10:16, 10:16, 10:17, 10:17.
These scripts are writing some log files also.
I am running it in Apple McBook Air, with OS X 12.4.0 Darwin

Comment: The crontab syntax is correct. Are the scripts executable (rwx-r-xr-x)? Does `/Users/sri/files/BatchFF.sh` start other scripts (run `grep Batch /Users/sri/files/BatchFF.sh`? I'd suggest that you add to the beginning of each script a line like `echo "$(date): $(basename $0) started" >> /tmp/debug.txt` to keep track when the are started in `/tmp/debug.txt`.

Comment: Yes, the scripts are executable, and also have logging support as the script gets completed a report is being generated. This script is calling a java application to run in a browser and log of which is stored in a folder. the folder is being created with the date and time when the process is started, thus, bcz of which I was able to detect the time they started.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you look into using LaunchD. Cron is officially deprecated on OSX. LaunchD has a lot of really nice features too.

The plist files can be a pain at first, but you get used to them.

Something like this can help:

http://blog.mattbrock.co.uk/2010/02/25/moving-from-cron-to-launchd-on-mac-os-x-server/

It can be as simple as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>BatchFF</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/sri/files/BatchFF.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Save the file as batchFF.plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents